# Automated Document Level Alerts

Tags: 2013

I am trying to have an alert sent to the creator of a document when the status of the document changes. I am aware that I can have users set up an alert for themselves, but I would like to automate this for a particular document library.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible in case of creating a simple workflow via SharePoint Designer that start automatically when item changed on your list / document library.

- In workflow steps add if condition to check the value of the document status.
- Then Add an action `Send an Email` that will be fire once the condition become true.
- Set `To` to `the user who created current item` as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, in the process of getting Designer installed. Will mark as the answer if/when I am able to try this and it works.

Comment: take your time, hope it helps you :)